# AutoMapper .AfterMap() vs .ForMember()

Tags: c#, automapper

I was facing an issue where I could use the .AfterMap() method or the .ForMember() method from AutoMapper. I was researching a little bit but did not find any information about it. What is the difference between them or when would you use one over the other?

**AfterMap**:

```
.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.SomeDestinationProperty = src.SomeSourceProperty);
```

**ForMember**:

```
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.SomeDestinationProperty,
    opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SomeSourceProperty)
);
```

Comment: `AfterMap` is just an escape hatch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AfterMap` is code that executes after AutoMaper has done its work. AutoMapper knows nothing about it (it is a black box) and cannot use any logic within it.

`ForMember` specifies the mapping for a single member but the real magic happens when used with `MapFrom`. In this combination AutoMapper knows exactly how to map one member to the other and it can automatically create a reverse mapping. It also allows you to use `ProjectTo` in LINQ which will result in more optimal queries (especially if your DTO includes only few of the fields in your entity(s)).

Comment: Also, validation. Because `AfterMap` is a black box, AM doesn't know what members are mapped that way.